# How to best generate text from analysis done in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have done some analysis within a Jupyter notebook. It's quite a lot (tables etc.) and now I want to generate some text to highlight specific areas. The context is financial analysis.

So here an example I want to generate:

```
In <March 2022> most money (<AMOUNT>) was spent on <Category Level 0>, which is <AMOUNT 1> more/less than in the previous month and <AMOUNT 2> more/less than in the previous year.
```

Currently I am thinking to use:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<h1>Analysis for</h1>'))
```

But this will be quite ugly as I need to stitch everything together.
Is there a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks a lot for your directions

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a function that returns a formatted string? You could reuse this easily.

```py
def formatData(date, amount, categoryLevel, amount1, amount2):
    return "In {} most money {} was spent on {}, which is {} more/less than in the previous month and {} more/less than in the previous year.".format(date, amount, categoryLevel, amount1, amount2)
```

Then call it on each datum as follows

```py
from datetime import date
formatData(date.today(), 2000, "Category Level 1", 200, 100)
```

which yields to

```py
'In 2022-02-22 most money 2000 was spent on Category Level 1, which is 200 more/less than in the previous month and 100 more/less than in the previous year.'
```

This obviously works with all data types. You could then generate HTML or Markdown in order to create a report file in the desired format.